# How to conditionally install documentation to pkghtmldir using Automake

Tags: doxygen, autotools, automake

I have a recipe in Automake that optionally builds documentation *if* the user issues `make doc` or `make htmldoc`:

```
if DOXYGEN_AVAILABLE

docs html htmldoc html-doc:
    $(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile -d DOXYGEN_PROCESSING

fi
```

`DOXYGEN_AVAILABLE` is set in `configure` based on the result of `AC_CHECK_PROGS`. If the docs are built there will be a directory `html-doc`. The documentation is optional and `html-doc` may be missing.

If `html-doc` is present I won't have a file list. I *don't* believe this will work in `Makefile.am`:

```
if DOXYGEN_AVAILABLE

docs html htmldoc html-doc:
    $(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile -d DOXYGEN_PROCESSING

pkghtmldir_FILES += html-doc/

fi
```

How do I optionally install documentation to `pkghtmldir` when using Automake?

Comment: A bit OT. I don't understand the  line `$(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile -d DOXYGEN_PROCESSING` especially the `-d ...` part. I assume that `$(DOXYGEN) is the `doxygen` executable, in that case the `-d ...` part will be ignored. Furthermore the problem here is not a doxygen problem.

Comment: @albert - I believe `-d` defines a C macro. For the project some code is in a `DOXYGEN_PROCESSING` block to help ensure the documentation is pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in the first place that you change your logic a bit.  If it's OK to not install the Doxygen docs when Doxygen isn't available to build them, then it should also be OK not to install them even if Doxygen *is* available.  Thus, it makes sense to use an `--enable-docs` or `--with-docs` or similar option to `configure` to let the package builder express whether the docs should be built, with whichever default suits you.  You could also consider including pre-built docs with your package, and then selecting whether to enable *re*building them.

You can furthermore, then, altogether omit the check for Doxygen when docs are not requested anyway, and emit a warning or error when they are requested but Doxygen is not available (or is too old).  That should be less surprising to package builders.  At least, it would be less surprising to *me*.

Still, it ultimately comes down to Automake conditionals either way.  Here's a slightly trimmed version of how I handle pretty much the same task in one of my projects:

**$(top_srcdir)/Makefile.am**:

```
# An Automake conditional:
if make_docs

# The name of the target(s) that encompasses actually building the docs
doxygen_html_targets = dox-html

# My Doxyfile is built by the build system, and the docs also depend on some example
# sources, stylesheets, and other files provided by the package.  All these are
# listed here, so that the docs are rebuilt if any of them change:
dox_deps = Doxyfile ...

# How to actually install the docs (a one-line make recipe).  Covers also installing
# pre-built docs that I include in the package for convenience, though this example
# has most of the other plumbing for that removed.
#
# The chmod in the below command must ensure the target files writable
# in order to work around weirdness in the behavior of the "distcheck" target
# when not configured to rebuild docs.
html_install = test -d dox-html && html_dir=dox-html || html_dir=$(srcdir)/dox-html; \
  $(MKDIR_P) $(DESTDIR)$(pkgdocdir); \
  cp -pR $${html_dir} $(DESTDIR)$(pkgdocdir)/html; \
  chmod -R u+w,go+rX $(DESTDIR)$(pkgdocdir)/html

else

doxygen_html_targets =
dox_deps =
html_install = :

endif

# The variable prerequisites of this rule are how the selection is made between
# building the docs and not building them:
html-local: $(doxygen_html_targets)
        :

## This rule should not be necessary, but Automake seems otherwise to ignore the 
## install-html-local rule, perhaps because there are no targets with an HTML
## primary.
install-data-local: install-html-local

# The variable recipe for this rule is how the selection is made between installing
# the docs and not installing them:
install-html-local:
        $(html_install)

maintainer-clean-local:
        $(RM) -rf dox-html

# This rule, when exercised, is what actually builds the docs:
dox-html: $(dox_deps)
        $(RM) -rf dox-html
        $(DOXYGEN) Doxyfile
```

The key thing to take away here is that it's not only file lists that you can store in `make` variables and control via Automake conditionals.  You can also store the names of arbitrary targets, to be used in prerequisite lists, and you can even store the text of rule recipes, so as to vary behavior of the rules that are selected.